# git rebase add master commit to the branch

Tags: git, rebase

While doing `git rebase master branch_a`, the commit that are coming from other branch are also included in my branch. I started with original branch state as seen below

[image: The original branch state]

after that, I executed rebase using `git rebase master branch_a` and then this happens

[image: the state after rebase]

I thought rebase will move the commit `E` root to `I`. is there problem with how I perform rebase?

UPDATE : I wrongly type the command, I used `git rebase master branch_a`

Comment: `git rebase branch_a master` means `git rebase --onto branch_a branch_a master`, which in turn means `git checkout master; git rebase branch_a`, which means it ends up changing the name `master` in the end. That's clearly not what you want, and not what you described either, so it's not what you actually ran.

Comment: If you actually ran `git rebase --onto branch_a master`, you would get what you drew. I think that is what you ran.

Comment: sorry I wrongly type the command in this question. I actually use `git rebase master branch_a`. I will update the question.

Comment: OK, `git rebase master branch_a` should have worked and done what you intended (I believe). I prefer to do a separate `git checkout` or `git switch`, followed by `git rebase` with one fewer arguments, but the effect should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the command you ran:

```sh
git rebase branch_a master
```

This form means "*checkout `master` and rebase it on top of `branch_a`*".

From the [documentation of `git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_description):

> `git rebase master topic`
>
> [...] [this] form is just a short-hand of `git checkout topic` followed by `git rebase master`. When rebase exits topic will remain the checked-out branch.

What you're looking for is:

```sh
git rebase master branch_a
```

which means "*checkout `branch_a` and rebase it on top of `master`*".

Comment: hi @enrico, sorry I made mistake in the question. I already use `git rebase master branch_a`. I've updated my question